# python write CD/DVD iso file

Tags: python, file, system, iso

I'm making a cross-platform (Windows and OS X) with wxPython that will be compiled to exe later.

Is it possible for me to create ISO files for CDs or DVDs in Python to burn a data disc with?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following 'do not reinvent the wheel' I would try using `mkisofs` (part of cdrtools) (although originating on Linux, I think there are windows builds floating around the net).

Comment: If you really want to make it look like Python, use `subprocess.Popen('mkisofs'...)`